# Norm of elements in number field are rational

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $Hom(K,\mathbb{C})$ be the set of $\mathbb{Q}-$homomorphisms from $K$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Define the norm of $a\in K$ to be $$N(a)=\prod_{\sigma \in Hom(K,\mathbb{C})}\sigma(a)$$

And we want to prove that $N(a)$ is a rational number.

I saw a proof somewhere but I couldn't understand it well:

**A possible proof**

Suppose $\tau\in Gal(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$

Since by replacing every $\sigma(a)$ by $\tau\sigma(a)$ we get a permutation of the product in the definition of $N(a)$, so we can easily have $$\tau(N(a))=\prod_{\sigma}\tau\sigma(a)=N(a)$$

By this we have $N(a)\in \mathbb{Q}$

**My confusion about this proof**

I have no idea about the fixed field of the galois group $Gal(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$, so I don't know why we can deduce $N(a)\in \mathbb{Q}$ from the above equation.

My question is: why is the above "proof" valid or not?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't like your definition of the norm for a field extension of $\mathbf Q$, since you make it depend on the crutch of using such a massive field like $\mathbf C$.  Why do you want to do that? Also, the notation ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf Q)$ is bad: the field extension $\mathbf C/\mathbf Q$ is *not* Galois so don't write its automorphism group as if it were a Galois group.  A simpler definition of the norm for a finite field extension $E/F$ is ${\rm N}_{E/F}(\alpha)  = {\rm det}(m_\alpha)$ where $m_\alpha \colon E \rightarrow E$ is the multiplication-by-$\alpha$ mapping.

Comment: Using that definition does not require leaving $E$ at all and it is obvious that its values are in the base field $F$.

Comment: It seems that your $N(a)$ is just the product of the conjugates of $a$ = the product of all the roots of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over Q = $\pm $ the constant term of this polynomial, hence it lives in Q. Note that you could have replaced C by an algebraic closure of Q.